# How do we animate a nav bar this way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/5jRXK/).

I want to:

- Have the `nav ul li` highlighted, slid to the leftmost and also have an animated shadow to represent lifting.
- Have the above changes reversed as the mouse pointer leaves the nav bar.

My code here has been accompanied with:

- `jquery.min.js`
- `jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js`
- `jquery.animate-shadow-min.js`

This code does not work though I find nothing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var linearOffset = $("nav li:hover").offset().left;
    $("nav li").mouseenter(function () {
        $("nav li:hover").removeClass("disappear");
        $("nav li:hover").addClass("appear");
        $(".disappear").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $(".appear").animate({
            right: linearOffset,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(5, 0, 234, 0.95)',
            color: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
        });
        $(".appear").stop(true, true);
        $(".appear").css("position", "absolute");
        var backupOffset = linearOffset;
        delete linearOffset;
    });
    $("nav").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".appear").stop();
        $(".appear").animate({
            left: linearOffset,
        });
        $(".disappear").css("visiblity", "visible");
        $(".appear").addClass("disappear");
        $(".appear").removeClass("appear");
    });
});
```

My working platform is Google Chrome 30.0.1599.101 (Official Build 227552) on Windows 8.

Comment: So each li should slide to the left when you hover over it, thus moving away from under your cursor? This is strange, it means you will need to do an extra mouse move to the left just to be able to click on it.

Comment: Before it all went wrong, it pretty much well worked, even though it snapped back the second hover. Each li is meant to be a label and not a link.

Comment: Can you really use :hover like that? http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: you can do it easily with CSS and no need  to JQuery codes!

Comment: this is CSS version of what you want `:)` : http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/5jRXK/1/

Comment: I don't see any reason to use javascript for this either. CSS!

Comment: Good JSFiddle @mohsen, but the OP wants it to move left?

Comment: @RichPeck what moves left ?

Comment: "Have the nav ul li highlighted, slid to the leftmost and also have an animated shadow to represent lifting."

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I thought he meant to slide the hovered element to the left; but maybe he meant that he wanted the `ul` positioned on the left

Comment: @RichPeck u got it right. i meant the hovered li should slide to the left and the other lis should fade and disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS and HTML is too long so I just link [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/5jRXK/5/).

here is JQuery:

```
$(".disappear").on('mouseenter', mEnter)
$('nav>ul').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $('.disappear').stop();
        $('.active').removeClass("active")
            .addClass("disappear");
        $(".disappear").show(700);
    });


function mEnter() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).removeClass("disappear");
        $(".disappear").hide(700);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for that. The basic idea is this: http://jsfiddle.net/TCDT5/ All li should be hidden except the hovered li when hovered. The hovered li should slide tho the left and the sub menu should appear on the right side of the hovered li (with any effect). Please help

Comment: BTW is there any way for the sub menu to appear on the right side of the hovered li?

Comment: @RithvikVibhu: yes there is. here is the code:http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/5jRXK/6/

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear. i meant the sub nav to be inline to the right side of the hovered li. the sub menu should be styled like the other main li when they are not hidden.